# How to find if the most common value of a column appears more than X% times?

Tags: pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
  ID   Column
0 500  2
1 500  2
2 500  2
3 500  2
4 500  2
5 500  4
```

How can we see if the most common value of 'Column' appears more than X% of the times?

I've tried to do: `df.locate[df.groupby('ID')['Column'].count_values(normalize=True).max() > X]` , but I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you had was close to a solution. It's not really clear to me, if you want to calculate this just over the whole column, or per group, so here's a solution for both. You can change variable `at_least_this_proportion`, to change the minimum threshold:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text = """
  ID   Column
0 500  2
1 500  2
2 500  2
3 500  2
4 500  2
5 500  4
6 501  2
7 501  2
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), header=0, sep='\s+')

# set minimum threshold
at_least_this_proportion = 0.5
```

Calculate per group:

```
# find the value that occurs at least 50% within its group
value_counts_per_group = df.groupby('ID')['Column'].value_counts(normalize=True)
ids_that_meet_threshold = value_counts_per_group[value_counts_per_group > at_least_this_proportion].index.get_level_values(0)

# get all rows for which the id meets the threshold
df[df['ID'].isin(ids_that_meet_threshold)]
```

Comment: I did not clarify it properly. I wanted the second one (i.e. per group). Thank you for providing both though! However, I'd like the output to be all the rows whose ID meets the condition. In the example you gave, all rows meet this condition. That is to say that, even the 5th row (500 4) would be True and thus returned.

Comment: ok, changed the solution: finding id's that meet the threshold and getting all rows for those ids